# Find files with data errors

Tags: windows

I have to back up a lot of files from DVDs. I am encountering cyclic redundancy check errors for some of the files. I am wondering if there is a Windows command line utility that will find all files with CRC errors so that I can skip them during the backup. Thanks.

Comment: Question:  Do you need the files with errors, would you like a recommendation on possibilities of fixing them.

Comment: I just need the files with errors.

Comment: A good CD/DVD cleaning resurfacing kit will clear up a lot of these kind of errors.

Answer (score 2):

A Cyclic Redundancy Check error is caused when data on the hard-drive or DVD becomes corrupt

1. Run CMD as an Administrator
2. type **chkdsk G: /f /r** ( 'G' signifies the affected Drive)
3. Run DiskPart utility from the same command prompt type **DiskPart** in the cmd
4. Once utility is loaded run **rescan** command. This command locates new disks that might have been added to the computer
5. I hope it would help you..

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question. I am backing up files from lots of DVDs and I cannot run chkdsk on them. Got the message: The type of the file system is RAW. CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.